# Discord.js: how to get channel id using its name

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have channel name, and want to find its id, and send a message in there.
I have tried using both

```js
bot.channels.cache.get('name', 'channel name here');
```

and

```js
bot.channels.find('name', 'channel name here');
```

but neither of them seem to work. `find()` returns an error "bot.channels.find is not a function", while `cache.get()` returns nothing. Help?

Also, I have not been able to find any similar question with a working answer in here.

EDIT: I learned that `cache.get()` requires the channel id, not its name. Still can't find out how to get channel id by its name though.

Answer (score 2):

For v12:

```js
bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "channel_name_here");
```

`<Collection>.find()` takes in a callback where each value of the collection is given.

With the upper code it gives us each channel object and we check if the name of that channel equals `"channel_name_here"`